# Doctrine Transactions Boundary

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions

I'm Using Doctrine ORM 2.5. I want to know if I need to wrap anything other than `$entityManager->flush()` in `$entityManager->beginTransaction()` and `$entityManager->commit()` when trying to Insert\Update\Remove Entities. Because in [Doctrine's Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly), other statements like `$user = new User()` is also wrapped in transaction calls.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be fine to have only the flush() within the beginTransaction and commit statement (of course as long as your using the same entity manager for all actions before)

But if that's your only "call" why marking your transaction boundaries anyway?
So what are you trying to achieve by setting the transaction boundaries?

Comment: The Use case is: I have multiple Entity Managers, and the changes to all of them should be rolled back, in case one of them encounters an error.

Comment: Do you have any sources for your statement?

Comment: That is why I wrote 'as long as your using the same entity manager', I can't say anything valid about the behaviour involving more than one entity manager. The source is the official doctrine documentation (see your own link), telling that 'flush' is starting a transaction implicitly and executing any statement in the UnitOfWork (in its specific orders etc.) with a rollback if anything happens.